# Solving a power series centered at 0 by integrating another power series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

Problem: Find the power series for g(x) centered at 0 by integrating the power series f(x). Give answer in sigma notation along with the first four nonzero terms.

$$g(x)=\ln{(1-3x)}\space \land \space f(x)=\frac{1}{1-3x}$$

I'm struggling to understand whether I've provided the appropriate answer. Any helpful hints would be much appreciated. Here's my work.

I begin with the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Then I integrate:

$\int \frac{1}{1-3x}dx \space=\space\int \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3x)^k dx \space=\space \int(1+3x+\frac{(3x)^2}{2}+\frac{(3x)^3}{3}+\cdots)dx$

Then multiply by -3:

$-\frac{\ln{(1-3x)}}{3}+C \space=\space \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(3x)^{k+1}}{k+1}+C \space=\space x+\frac{(3x)^2}{2}+\frac{(3x)^3}{3}+\cdots+C$

$\ln{(1-3x)} \space=\space -3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3x)^{k+1}}{k+1}+C \space=\space -3(x+\frac{(3x)^2}{2}+\frac{(3x)^3}{3}+\cdots) +C$

$\therefore \space \ln(1-3x) \space=\space -3\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3x)^{k+1}}{k+1} \space=\space -3x-\frac{3*(3x)^2}{2}-\frac{3*(3x)^3}{3}-\frac{3*(3x)^4}{4}-\cdots$

Is this correct, or am I missing something? I keep thinking I'm missing something with the constant $C$. Also, Should this be represented as a Maclaurin series?

Comment: When you integrate with power series, you indeed have to account for a possible constant $C$. In this case, the constant turns out to be zero (after plugging in for $x$ the value of 0)

Comment: Right. That's my justification for dropping the constant from my final answer, but it seemed so strange to do so!

Comment: Look, if this were to be a problem on a quiz, and the student would not even mention the possibility of a constant, the student would lose some credit here. So even though the C is zero here, you should mention to your instructor that you considered a possible C by showing that for $x=0$, LHS and RHS agree and thus a constant is not needed.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: Hmm, apparently my answer is incorrect. Should be $-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3^k * x^k}{k}$.

Comment: can you integrate $(3x)^k$ please ?

Comment: Oh my, that's embarrassing. Good eyes!

Comment: Well, that can happen to all of us...i didn't catch it either...:)